# chunk results of meteor Easy Search

Tags: meteor, meteor-easy-search

Hi I use the matteodem:easy-search package for Meteor. Right now I am chunking my results into groups of `size`

```
Template.UserList.helpers({
  users: function () {
    all = Meteor.users.find().fetch();
    chunks = [];
    size = 3;
    while (all.length > size) {
      chunks.push({ row: all.slice(0, size)});
      all = all.slice(size);
    }
    chunks.push({row: all});
    return chunks;
  }
});
```

and it works like a charme, but now I want to know how to do this with

`{{#EasySearch.Each index=playersIndex }}`

since you can't split the Index. Anyone have an idea to get EasySearch.Each work with Bootstrap row?

thanks.

Comment: can't you just replace the find call with a call to your `EasySearch.Index`?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at what `EasySearch.Each` does (https://github.com/matteodem/meteor-easy-search/blob/master/packages/easysearch:components/lib/each/each.js) it seems that you can just use

```
index.getComponentMethods().getCursor()
```

once you've created your index, i.e., just replace your find call with the above and it might work.